# Select value from moday this week on 18:00

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I'm trying to get values from MySQL only on monday current week and from 18:00 to 19:00. How I can do this?

The result should be: 1

```
m_z_analytics

|id|m_type|date_added         |
|1 |test1 |2018-06-25 18:02:09|
|2 |test2 |2018-06-26 19:44:24|


SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM m_z_analytics WHERE
Week(date_added) = Week(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND
date_added >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
date_added < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WEEKDAY()` or `DAYNAME()` function to test the day of week and `HOUR()` to test the time of day.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM m_z_analytics
WHERE date_added BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR
AND HOUR(date_added) = 18
AND DAYNAME(date_added) = 'Monday'
```

You don't need the `WEEK()` function, since the time interval narrows to the current week.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Full line look like this: `$dh_c_01_01 = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM m_z_analytics WHERE date_added BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) BETWEEN 18 and 19 AND DAYNAME(date_added) = 'Monday'");` (using php 5.6)

Comment: Do you want to include the second row in the count? 19:44 is after 19:00.

Comment: PHP version is irrelevant, this is just MySQL.

Comment: No, only this one but I have no idea why your code don't work.

Comment: That's why I used `HOUR(date_added) = 18` instead of `BETWEEN 18 AND 19`, since the latter will include `19:xx`.

Comment: The current time here is `16:21`, so Monday 18:00 is not before `NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR`.

Comment: Sure, but this should depend on `date_added` time, not on code or server time.

Comment: **current** week depends on server time. Why do you have `date_added < (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR)` if it's OK to get a time a few hours in the future.

Comment: Ok, I found issue. From your order it doesn't work for me but I tried change places and now works `AND date_added BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DAYNAME(date_added) = 'Monday' AND HOUR(date_added) = 18 AND NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR`.

Comment: `BETWEEN` needs two dates after it, not just one.

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. You're using `DAYNAME(date_added) = 'Monday'` as the second date in the `BETWEEN` range.

Comment: Apparently the order matters, the most important is that it works.

Comment: No, the most important thing here is to understand **why** it works.

Comment: It's probably just an accident that it seems to get the right answer, and it doesn't work in general.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates it with more data?